# Function to check number of rows in a div does not work in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, overflow

The following piece of code is used to check how many lines (clarify: lines of text) a target div can contain before overflowing (y-overflow).

It works by making a clone of the DOM element, emptying its contents, then appending `<br>` tags one at a time (to force new line), checking each time for overflow (by checking whether scrollHeight > clientHeight).

While debugging I noticed that it works in Chome and FF, but in IE9 the vertical scroll bar never appears no matter how many 
 tags are inserted, and thus the loop never exits properly. Any idea how to make it work with IE?

http://jsfiddle.net/zbdbq/5/

```
function checkNumRows (obj){
    var overflow = false, rows = 0;

    var measureDiv = obj.clone().empty().css('overflow', 'auto'); //make a clone of the original
    measureDiv.appendTo(obj.parent()); //append it to DOM
    while (!overflow && rows < 500) {//set upper limit to 500 rows to prevent infinite looping for whatever reason
        measureDiv.append('<br>');
        overflow = measureDiv[0].scrollHeight > measureDiv[0].clientHeight ? true : false;
        rows = rows + 1;
    }

    measureDiv.remove(); //cleanup
    return rows - 1; //return max rows before overflow occured
}

alert(checkNumRows($("#testDiv"))); //IE incorrectly returns num rows as the max 499​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minimal changes to your code try appending a bit of "content" when you add the items to your cloned element.  I can't 100% recall, but I seem to remember that IE enjoys collapsing white space which can lead to some perceived funky behavior --

In your fiddle you call empty() (which empties the element) and then proceed to append some br elements which are empty themselves --

```
 var measureDiv = obj.clone().empty().css('overflow', 'auto');
```

One option is to add some content to prevent this -- ie `.append('&nbsp;<br>')` http://jsfiddle.net/zbdbq/9

I suppose in the same vein you could just make sure you don't have an empty element to begin with -- `obj.clone().empty().html('&nbsp;')...` http://jsfiddle.net/zbdbq/10/

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
function checkNumRows (obj){
    var measureDiv = obj.clone().empty().appendTo(obj.parent());

    $span = $('<span>X</span>').appendTo(measureDiv);
    rows = Math.floor(measureDiv.height() / $span.height());

    measureDiv.remove();
    return rows;
}

alert(checkNumRows($("#testDiv")));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zbdbq/13/

maybe play around with `$span.outerHeight()` to get better results..

Comment: It works, but it returns 1 more row than Chrome (16 in IE rather than 15 in Chrome). 15 is the correct number.

Comment: the different results are because the both browsers render the font differntly high. See in both browsers http://jsfiddle.net/zbdbq/15/ to see the difference

Answer (score 1):

If by "lines" you mean automatically sized inline elements, you could try checking based on the lineHeight CSS style.

```
function checkNumRows(obj) {
    var line_height = parseInt(obj.css('lineHeight').replace('/em|px/', ''));
    var max_rows = Math.floor(obj.height()/line_height);

    return max_rows;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery by the looks of things you should just do this directly:

```
$("#myTable > tbody > tr").length
```

That function will only count the rows in the immediate table specified with "myTable" here.  If you wish to account for *nested tables* too then you should use:

```
$('#myTable tr').length;
```

Comment: I currently don't have any tables, but inserting a table and rows would be an alternative approach I hadn't thought of (opposed to inserting br tags). Question is, how would I know how many rows to insert to make it just fit?